# Visiting all nodes in a grid using pathfinding?

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search, path-finding

In our semester project we're attempting to make a small car which can search an area for metal in the ground. Each time it encounters an object in the ground, it has to mark down the coordinates for it, and find a path around it to visit all remaining nodes.

We've implemented a way in which we can get the area noted down in a grid, so we have it all in a x-y coordinate. We've considered using a modified version of a pathfinding algorithm (breadth-first, A* or other) to find our way through the system, but we're having trouble with the implementation of it.

Is it possible to modify any of these algorithms so instead of going from node A to B, it searches each coordinate, and "re-paths" if it encounters an object in the ground?

Comment: put all cells in "not visited list", at start, while "not visited" list is not empty, construct path from current cell to first from the list. Upon entering cell, check if it is in "not visited" list and remove if it is, and do your stuff in the cell. It is not the most efficient way, but quite easy to implement using existing path-finding algorithm without modifying it.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur I've done this, and implemented a function that traverses all nodes in a list. My issue is, that each node must have both x- and y-coordinates, so I can send information to the car, to make it turn etc. whenever it encounters a "corner". I'm having trouble understanding how to implement this however, do you happen to have any pointers?

Comment: If you show us your code we will be able to give you some pointers @Emil

Answer (score 0):

## Logic

So first, we check all the squares if they contain metal.  Then we store the squares with metal in a boolean grid.

## Pseudo-Code

```
bool grid[10000][10000];
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
       if (square is metal){
           grid[i][j] = true; //means its visited.
       }
    }
}
//Conduct bfs here
typedef pair<int , int> pi; //introduce priority queues
typedef pair<pi, int> ppi;
int dx[8] = {-1,-2, 1 ,2 ,-1, -2, 1, 2};//introduce movement coordinates
int dy[8] = {-2,-1, -2,-1, 2, 1, 2, 1};
//Check if the coordinates of the grid is true(visited) or false(unvisited)
```

Hope this helps.